# Electric arc due to static discharge in a T-Shirt possible?

Tags: electricity, electrostatics

Yesterday, when I came home, I went to the bathroom (lights off) and i took off my T-Shirt (100% cotton) which I wore under a Shirt (50% cotton, 50% polyester). I *believe* to have seen a small but well visible light arc.

**Question:** Is the amount of static discharge in T-Shirt big enough to produce a visible light arc?

Comment: If it were wool, it would be possible.

Comment: I was wearing a wool suit that evening. And there was definitely some static electricity, I felt it when i took the T-Shirt off. But I'm also curious why that would happen with a cotton shirt.

Comment: I see this occasionally myself with my own shirts (100% cotton), so you are not by yourself on this one.

Comment: I've also seen the same effect with fleece blankets late at night during dry times of the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cotton is above polyester in the [triboelectric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Triboelectric_series).

So it seems likely that the cotton shirt gained positive charge, and the 50% cotton 50% polyester shirt gained negative charge, and arcs formed.